# Using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser for Google App Status

Tags: php, parsing, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

I wanted to use PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser to grab the Google Apps Status table so I can create my own dashboard that will only include Google Mail and Google Talk service status, as well as change the presentation (html,css).

As a test, I wanted to find/output the table element but it's not displaying any results.

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/appsstatus');
$e = $html->find("table", 0);
echo $e->outertext;
```

Although, if I find/output the div elements it will display results.

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/appsstatus');
$e = $html->find("div", 0);
echo $e->outertext;
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's way easier than that.  All of this data is tied up in a JSON feed.

http://www.google.com/appsstatus/json/en

On a simple level, you could do a `file_get_contents()` of that, knock that bit off the front that says `dashboard.jsonp`, and then to a `json_decode()` ([doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)), and you will have yourself a nice array with all the information you'd ever want to know about Google's service status.  Dump it with `print_r()` to see where everything is.

Finding these types of things is super easy with [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).  I highly recommend it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Brad. Accessing Google's feed was something I was going to do but I wanted to a visual presentation that I can display on a Website like a Monitoring Network Service Dashboard. All I really want is the "Today's Status" with the text "No issues" and the tick image.

Comment: Sure, but the data source *is* that feed.  The text with "no issues" is generated client side.  That's how that page works.

Comment: Great stuff. Thanks again Brad, I really appreciate your help.